# Imported network request to sign in not producing same results in postman

Tags: rest, postman, restful-authentication

I'm trying to scrape information from my account on Barnes and Noble, here: https://press.barnesandnoble.com/sign-in

When signing in, I track the network request and copy as curl(bash).

I then import this into postman (I have to remove the -H 'cookie: .... ' part and add that manually as it won't import). This is what I'm importing.

```bash
curl 'https://press.barnesandnoble.com/api/authentication/signin' \
  -H 'authority: press.barnesandnoble.com' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=aQm1BCFP6jYJ9nvRHlx%2F%2FqNTnc33EiR%2FVDF1B%2FVN6ug%3D; bm_sz=2C67B2C3CFF64CAAEA28009A2D17DB83~YAAQto57XNKnrPKJAQAArNTg+BRepw8NxA6WFn8HGTW97nIJxdxiKd3pK7OW0ec2BqM36BP62EDjbxsE/2UGd5wGdQU7uMfwHLV0GIf+/jXHgKzvRHSItUIlrxW9QW8cE88kscsYu/iNan2E4NWdRXpSBvjlZ8JJKGk5MX/vpWrTkDnLdRj+86muC9yFIRpzKb1J7pPMbEcerVm8QUImOImSoBShIxAaNX332ECJriRNylTQEOy4mXDIZmuLpJE7k+8JBG6X8UJPMUOMT7nftT8GqZe6I2BE9rzdCQwUuNtRFMTdUnNn3jcT9g==~4535106~3360053; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1692097632047r0.668805033726956; _gcl_au=1.1.222399726.1692097632; _gid=GA1.2.1785033297.1692097633; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.1.53917089.1692097633; _abck=DE294BB1388B1E1F6FEEE9CF022D8D18~0~YAAQto57XPynrPKJAQAAbNrg+ApqfLfwgt0ohkQxMHWq9If6n9AocvtycEyDhwZDhEuvnfOexft12iiQE/iSv8LesjR+LbZ/DDTvFHxQmq0ifFn18dyHbgrH+PXUdWJ/quteZh8WbVUZoYlbSUjaMGlThsr0ZACBUGsIHlCSfEfsOYP43Ujf6FQt4PznYdVkuxMdVZT/KE4c7qfCjyjIgKaf9TIqosA2f0vfepYZ7ZWr/bHyehLUSuDGucdflJMSpwAHzBmnh0DxTiaDKDsEIaD0TlNkBhOKzLsHeMDhkdYUOi4nRI3rot0QqAoJfxKhN7XsGSbdyA6UUuwHzdeyXABGyZzVnRO9K4x/lfxoI6i3K56miaJqlovGmXM+LW2BN5SkX8i+vVn4SZWA8cU7WNd8cC/aSLIdU/k8k2wjaNA=~-1~||-1||~-1; _ga_6V609DDE0L=GS1.1.1692097632.1.1.1692097633.0.0.0; _ga_6X7XQGDRX5=GS1.2.1692097633.1.0.1692097633.0.0.0; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Tue+Aug+15+2023+12%3A07%3A13+GMT%2B0100+(British+Summer+Time)&version=6.6.0&hosts=&consentId=06f6ffd5-da0a-42c7-a897-833c999ea67a&interactionCount=0&landingPath=https%3A%2F%2Fpress.barnesandnoble.com%2Fsign-in&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1; ak_bmsc=30FBBFC318C05EF7C71C18B59A6806AC~000000000000000000000000000000~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; _nookpress_com_session=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--72fbbb550d3561ec03e3ce4c976dc8d8e329b4e6; bm_sv=F8649B380E19558561705C662C1D5ACE~YAAQto57XB+orPKJAQAAq9/g+BSxLc0Bk3u73krPJWa7C/MHmkj7Zl47BsQ8Ub2bcis4aEUuQajUwJVeESsZ6tD2TCcpmlx+Z2waTd8cvNh3Vu/DqwMMRvzoGAhb/8BMDXGHwzGAiljcMHaBiFnRyfcoKcGgLFhjErGybjo46KFU6IxaIHQEhY4iFPxC4QXOb76bOBvQgiRPh7ZZCPgMp7XxTk9ZrikJIZcUTh8KVG1PW3TiKwv411VyNtbbzK97HrVVPP+ub2g=~1; s_fid=50BFDE92581942BD-3A69D3053F8BDFA7; s_vnum=1693522800020%26vn%3D1; s_invisit=true; s_lv_s=First%20Visit; s_ppn=no%20value; s_ppvl=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_ppv=https%253A%2F%2Fpress.barnesandnoble.com%2Fsign-in%2C89%2C89%2C1321%2C2583%2C1321%2C5120%2C1440%2C1%2CP; s_depth=2; s_lv=1692097642658; s_sq=bannookpressprod%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fpress.barnesandnoble.com%25252Fsign-in%2526link%253DSign%252520In%2526region%253DBODY%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fpress.barnesandnoble.com%25252Fsign-in%2526oid%253DSign%252520In%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT' \
  -H 'origin: https://press.barnesandnoble.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://press.barnesandnoble.com/sign-in' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-xsrf-token: aQm1BCFP6jYJ9nvRHlx//qNTnc33EiR/VDF1B/VN6ug=' \
  --data-raw '{"email":"some@tests.com","password":"123123"}' \
  --compressed
```

When posting this in postman, I get a status 200 but with no data returned but in the browser I get a payload of:

```json
{
    "code": "SUCCESS",
    "payload": {
        "errors": "Your email and password combination does not match our records. Please try again.",
        "user": null
    }
}
```

Are there any tricks I need to be aware of to get this working?